# Where has Andre Murrall gone?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, story, sports

Renowned tennis player Andre Murrall seems to have left the tennis tournament he is currently playing in, Winbelldam. No one knows where he has gone except a taxi driver who claims he drove Murrall away from the tournament. However Andre has paid the taxi driver (Who is also very good at **Maths**) not to reveal his location specifically so when the media ask him about Murrall's location he hands over this:

The taxi driver gave this short speech and handed the interviewer these tennis scores:

> "He’s such a key player, count the numbers of the times that he's hit a winner, compare that to the letters he’s received from the queen, he is an all-time great.
>   What adds up is that you can take the mean out of him. After that you can still add up the mean-ness.
>   When you count all the games he and his opponents have played its incredible. 
>   How many times has he lost? 5, 11, 9, 3, 9, 1, 5… who knows! I just can’t help looking at the letters from players congratulating him.

[image: Tennis Scoreboard 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

Looking at these scores you can deduce that they are complete nonsense and bear no resemblance to the tournament at all. They must have some other hidden meaning which can be unlocked by something else...

> Where has Andre Murrall gone?

**NOTE: You only need (very) basic tennis knowledge**

Hints:

> There are 4 parts to this puzzle which lead to a 3 word sentence explaining where he's gone. Each 'part' relates to each paragraph of the interview.

2

> Key phrases in the paragraphs, to stop you going off on the wrong track
> 1. 'Count the numbers (digits)', 'compare that to the letters (in the players names)'
> 2. 'Adds up (digits in each separate match)', 'take the mean (and round it), 'add up the means'
> 3. 'Count all the games' (games as in tennis games)
> 4. '5, 11, 9, 3, 9, 1', 'compare to letters' (same as first paragraph but numbers given). 
> Compare the numbers you get from paragraphs 2 and 3 to the alphabet

Comment: Calling all/any Commonwealth subjects: Is a letter "from the queen" part of the culture? Do royalty play Scrabble on chess boards?

Comment: How come Murrall didn't play a game against Maddal ?

Comment: @Marius ;) it didn't fit

Comment: @humn I'll give you a hint, the queen but isn't important

Comment: The queen isn't important? How treasonous!

Comment: Idk much about tennis, but the maths phrases stand out: "count the numbers of the times he’s won, compare that to the letters", "What adds up... take the mean... add up the mean", "count all the games he and his opponents have played", and "How many times has he lost?".

Comment: @mbomb007 good start, some of those you don't need but the rest you do

Comment: Is this "`5, 11, 9, 3, 9, 1, 5… `" random or not?

Comment: @ABcDexter DEFINETLY not, most of the suspicious bits in the interview are relevant

Comment: Aah, interesting... Also, i think i see a pattern in current points in game, score of the current set, and can map it intp this above "5,11..." :)

Comment: Haven't made much progress but enjoy coming back to gaze at the authentic-looking pictures now and again. The variation in lights adds a satisfying naturalness, but good to know that it doesn't include steganography.

Comment: @ABcDexter, oh. I'll save you some time and tell you that is coincidence. The numbers don't refer to the points, games or sets, but something else

Comment: Ok, and I think there are different players as the tournament is in knockout  phase? and Murall defeated them all, assuming that the given order is correct for the actual matches played( if any)

Comment: @ABcDexter, sorry to disappoint you again, but this should be heeded by every one, it doesn't matter what stage the tournament is at, is he won or not or anything at all. I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: Do the scores actually matter or is it to give a natural look to the puzzle??

Comment: @Sid That's a lot of effort for a red herring.  It's pretty reasonable to assume that the scores matter.

Comment: @LeppyR64 actually Sid is sort of on to something. The scores don't necessarily matter, but maybe the digits do...

Comment: And Another question- What exactly is basic tennis knowledge? Just the knowledge of scores??

Comment: @Sid, you only need to know what sets, games, and points are

Comment: Is it significant that Thieem has 0 in the last column while a few others have 00?

Comment: letters received from the queen could be "Sir" as in a knighthood..

Comment: @DooplissForce, no that was a mistake. However it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Sid like I said before the queen bit doesn't matter

Comment: "How many times has he lost?" Does that refer to a game or a match?

Comment: @Sid, this is a tricky question, you have to identify what is important and what isn't. To help: the first few words in instructions, any math phrases and numbers are important. The rest is to add context

Comment: Are the scoreboard images ***visually*** significant (as in steganography), or is only their *textual* content (digits and letters) important? If the latter, it would be decent of you to post the essential data *as text*, so vision-impaired users have a chance to access the puzzle.

Comment: @PeregrineRook, digits and letters are important, I'm not very good at steganography. Displaying it as text I'm afraid wouldn't work. All you have to do is count and add up though so wouldn't make a difference anyway

Comment: As we don't know the game scores from the previous sets, can we assume the total number of games played in the previous sets does not matter?

Comment: @Drifter104, certainly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this has been abandoned. I'll post my answer myself as no one appears to have been anywhere close.

What you have to do for the first part is

> Add up each digit and count that number on the letters

Which you can get from the first paragraph

> **count the numbers** of the times that he's hit a winner, **compare that to the letters** he’s received from the queen

Doing this we get

> 9 (2, 2, 4, 1) = '**H**'
> 10 (1, 1, 5, 3) = '**O**'
> 10 (2, 1, 1, 5, 1) = '**L**'
> 16 (2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 2) = '**I**'
> 10 (2, 1, 5, 2) = '**D**'
> 9 (1, 1, 3, 4) = '**A**'
> 12 (1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4) = '**Y**'
> **Holiday**

For the second part

> You must add up the means for each match, round them, and then add up all the means

You get this from the second paragraph

> What **adds up** is that you can take **the mean** out of him. After that you can still **add up the mean-ness**.

So doing this we get

> 9 (2, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0) = 9 / 7 = 1.3 = **1**
> 10 (0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0) = 10 / 8 = 1.25 = **1** 
> 10 (2, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0) = 10 / 8 = 1.25 = **1**
> 16 (2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0) = 16 / 8 = **2**
> 10 (2, 0, 1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0) = 10 / 8 = 1.25 = **1**
> 9 (1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0) = 9 / 8 = 1.1 = **1**
> 12 (1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0) = 12 / 8 = 1.5 = **2**
> $1+1+1+2+1+1+2$ $=$ $9$
> And the $9$<sup>$th$</sup> letter of the alphabet is '**I**'

For the third part

> You simply count all the *tennis* games (excluding sets, just what it says on the board)

You get this from paragraph 3:

> When you **count all the games he and his opponents have played** it's incredible.

Doing this we get

> $2+1+1+1+4+2+1+1+1$ $=$ $14$
> And the $14$<sup>$th$</sup> letter of the alphabet is **N**

For the last part

> You compare the numbers '5, 11, 9, 3, 9, 1, 5' to the letters of the names, like the first part

You get this from

> The last paragraph where it says the numbers and then where it says ' I just can’t help **looking at the letters from players** congratulating him.'

Doing this we get:

> 5 = A
> 11 = C
> 9 = I
> 3 = R
> 9 = E
> 1 = M
> 5 = A
> And this says **AMERICA** backwards

So Andre Murall has gone on

> **HOLIDAY IN AMERICA**

Good for him :P

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(Community evidence locker— feel free to add or correct)</sup>

[Tennis scoring: match = sets × 6 games ×
      4 points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Match_score)

```
Scoreboard numbered out:
                                                               "times
     MATCH            SET            GAME           TOTAL       he's                 sum of
sets games pts     games pts      score pts       games pts     lost"               letters
--------------     ---------      ---------       ---------    ------               -------
                                                                         Murray -----  96
 "2"  12  48        "2"   8        "40"  3         14   59               Murrall ----  95
 "1"   6  24        "0"   0         "0"  0          6   24     ... 5 e   Thieem -----  60 ...
                                                               :     :   Thiem ------  55   :
                                                               :     :......::              :
 "0"   0   0        "1"   4        "15"  1          1    5     :         Murrall            :
 "0"   0   0        "0"   0        "30"  2          0    2     :  11 k   Dyockovich - 115   :
                                                               :     :   Djokovic ---  89   :
                                                               :     :......::              :
 "2"  12  48        "1"   4        "15"  1         13   53     :         Murrall            :
 "0"   0   0        "1"   4        "00"  0          1    4     :.. 9 i   Silich -----  60 ..:
                                                               :     :   Cilic ------  36   :
                                                               :     :....:.:               :
 "2"  12  48        "4"  16        "15"  1         16   65     :         Murrall            :
 "2"  12  48        "2"   8        "00"  0         14   56     :   3 c   Mishicori -- 103   :
                                                               :     :   Nishikori -- 112   :
                                                               :     :........:             :
 "2"  12  48        "0"   0        "15"  1         12   49     :         Murrall            :
 "2"  12  48        "0"   0        "00"  0         12   48     :.. 9 i   FedERROR ---  89 ..:
                                                               :     :   Federer ----  61   :
                                                               :     :.?                    :
 "1"   6  24        "1"   4        "30"  2          7   30     :         Murrall            :
 "0"   0   0        "0"   0        "40"  3          0    3     :   1 a   Warinker ---  99   :
                                                               :     :   Wawrinka --- 100   :
                                                               :     :..........:           :
 "1"   6  24        "1"   4        "30"  2          7   30     :         Murrall            :
 "2"  12  48        "1"   4        "40"  3         13   55     :.. 5 e   Birdytch ---  89 ..:
                                                                     :   Berdych ----  65
                                                                     :....:
```

Comment: From the OPs comment that he *could not* post an ASCII text version of the table, I would deduce that the *dots* in the score board are of some significance (*dots* are also *points*). Has anyone counted / used them already?

Comment: @BmyGuest, nice idea which I might use in the future, but the dots aren't important, just the digits themselves

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Ok, thanks for clarification. I, however, do not quite understand why it should then not be *possible* to state the puzzle using ASCII text as requested by Peregrene Rook. If this statement holds, then it contains some sort of hint, because then some feature of the images - which would get lost in the clean text representation - is of importance...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That is not to say, that I couldn't agree with a *esthetically motivated* reason to not do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just some stray observations:

count the numbers of the times that he's hit a winner

> Assuming only the points shown on the scoresheet, we get: 3+1+1+1+1+2+2=11. Its mean is 5.5(Which doesn't make a whole lot of sense)

When you count all the games he and his opponents have played

> Counting all, we get 7.

If we add what we got, I still can't make it work with something.
That's all I got so far. I can't get the lost part.

Comment: Heres some help: first paragraph contains 2 key phrases, 'count the numbers' and 'compare that to the letters'. The mean but is in second paragraph which means that's separate, and the 'count the games he and his opponents have played' refer to tennis games. For paragraphs 2 and 3 compare the numbers you get to the alphabet. Last paragraph contains key phrases '5, 11, 9, 3, 9, 1, 5' and 'looking at the letters'. For paragraphs 1 and 4, letters might just refer to the letters in the player's names. Hope you can get it now, You deserve the bounty because you've been most actively involved so far

Comment: thanks, for my active involvement, I was trying to solve it before winbeldaam gets over. But Now, it already has. But thanks again for the help. I was livid with myself for missing such obvious clues